# how to enable spring filter on conditional annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to design such feature with SpringBoot. Say there are 2 projects 'projectA' and 'projectB',
which B is a java library and A is depends on B.  there is a Filter 'FilterA' defined on B ,

now I would like add a custom annotation @EnableCustomBean. Only if I put the  @EnableCustomBean(class=FilterA.class), the FilterA will be work on projectA,
I've search some about spring @Conditional , but still no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You don't need any custom annotations - just use @ConditionalOnProperty:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "foo", name = "bar")
public YourFilterClass yourFilterClass() {
    ...
}
```

This bean will only be created if you define the foo.bar property

---

**Option 2:**

To satisfy your requirement of using custom Annotation you can:

1. define your own annotation
2. define custom condition:

   ```
   class MyCondition implements Condition {
       @Override
       public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
           return AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(MainApplication.getClass(),YourCustomAnnotation.class) != null;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use you custom condition with `@Conditional` over `@Bean` definition:

   ```
   @Bean
   @Conditional(MyCondition.class)
   public YourFilterClass yourFilterClass() {
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks  Asgarov , ConditionalOnProperty is a solution indeed, but i still prefer a custom @EnableXXX annotation on man class,  I don't like config file *.properties/ *.yml

Comment: updated my answer